# MySQL ORDER BY returns incorrect results for variable length strings

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-order-by

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags` (
  `tid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('spec','gen','cat','app','ep') DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
ALTER TABLE `tags` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`tid`);
ALTER TABLE `tags` MODIFY `tid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

```
╔═════╤═══════════════════════╤════════╗
║ tid │ name                  │ type   ║
╟─────┼───────────────────────┼────────╢
║   1 │ "spike"               │ NULL   ║
║   2 │ "gala dress"          │ 'app'  ║
║   3 │ "s1e1"                │ 'ep'   ║
║   4 │ "dragon"              │ 'spec' ║
║   5 │ "backgroud character" │ 'cat'  ║
║   6 │ "s1e2"                │ 'ep'   ║
║   7 │ "male"                │ 'gen'  ║
║   8 │ "s1e3"                │ 'ep'   ║
║   9 │ "main six"            │ 'cat'  ║
╚═════╧═══════════════════════╧════════╝
```

Running the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT type FROM `tags` ORDER BY type DESC
```

The result is not what I expected, `ep` is sorted to the top, while it should be after `cat`:

```
╔════════╗
║ type   ║
╟────────╢
║ 'ep'   ║
║ 'app'  ║
║ 'cat'  ║
║ 'gen'  ║
║ 'spec' ║
║ NULL   ║
╚════════╝
```

I assume this is because `'ep'` is shorter than the rest of the items, but how can I sort the table without shorter strings being sorted before longer ones?

In this specific case I *could* sort using the first character in each string, but I'd like a future-proof solution in case 2 types will start with the same letter(s) later.

Comment: Actually, alphabetically speaking 'ep' should be before 'cat' when your order by is DESC.

Comment: If you actually wrote `ORDER BY type DESC` the result is totally wrong, should be spec,gen,ep,cat,app,NULL (see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce3e1/1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your field is an `enum`, and mysql is sorting by the internal index value:

```
`type` enum('spec','gen','cat','app','ep') DEFAULT NULL
             0       1     3     4     5
```

when you sort `desc`, `ep` shows first because it has the HIGHEST index value.